# The Pirates of Beal Isle - very long logic grid puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, liars, mystery, logic-grid

## Story

*Let me tell ye a tale: Somewhere northeast o' the Bahamas there be a tiny scrap o' rocks stickin' up out o' the sea known as Beal Island. It be a barren, rocky place, and no man ever called it home. But many years ago, a band o' bloodthirsty pirates, with the king's navy swarmin' all over to catch them, hid their ill-gotten loot on the island. They were captured and thrown in jail for evadin' justice, but since they didn't have the treasure, none could prove they'd done the deed, and they escaped the gallows. They all swore that they'd meet gain on the island to dig up their treasure after they all got out o' jail.*

*More recently now, a mighty hurricane swept o'er Beal Island, leaving in its wake the wreckage of ill- fated ships dashed upon the rocks. The survivors banded together an' recovered those provisions what washed up on shore. They found caves in th' isle, and set up to wait fer a passin' ship to rescue 'em. However, it soon became apparent that some among 'em were there fer more nefarious purposes: **four** of the pirates had returned to gather their treasure! However, thanks to the brave actions o' the survivors, the pirates were found out before they recovered the treasure, an' all present held a great feast before hangin' the louts. But the pirates weren't so easily defeated. They poisoned the rum at the feast, and everyone fell into a stupor o' haunted dreams. When they awoke, none could remember who they were, nor what ship they'd been on, nor even who the pirates were!*

### Puzzle

This puzzle was originally designed as a mystery party, where the guests played the role of shipwrecked amnesiac sailors on a desert island, trying to figure out who they were. Each player was given some clues representing the few things that their character still remembered, but other clues were encoded in their dress and manner of speech. Each guest wore either an officer's hat, marking them as an officer, a bandana on their head, marking them as a sailor, or neither, marking them as a passenger. The passengers were all dressed either richly (paying passengers) or poorly (stowaways). Each player was also instructed to wear or not wear an eye-patch, hook-hand, or peg-leg. Finally, different players spoke using distinctive languages or accents.

Additional clues were available in the form of copies of crew and passenger manifests which had "washed up on the beach". The crew manifests clearly state the name and rank of every crew member on five different ships, and the names of the ships. However, since none of the castaways remember their names, this is only somewhat helpful, especially since many of the original crews were lost in the storm. The passenger manifests show the groups of passengers who were aboard ships, but not which ship they were aboard.

#### Goal

Determine the following:

**For each ship:** What country was it from, what was its last port of call, where was it bound to, and what type of ship was it.

**For each player:** What was their character's name and rank, what ship were they on, and were they a pirate.

**Bonus**:What is the language spoken by the characters whose language is marked as "strange"?

#### Assumptions

You may assume the following:

- All of the pirates' clues are false.
- Everyone else's clues are true.
- The **four** pirates were hidden aboard the various ships, among the crew, passengers, and/or stowaways.

  > **Edit**: Correction of earlier statement, which said "hidden among the crews", seeming to rule out the possibility of pirates among the passengers or stowaways.
  >   **Second edit**: There are actually four pirates.  The puzzle originally said three.
- The people who died in the storm were not present at the party, and nothing is known about them except what is given in the clues and the manifests.
- The various castaways have had several days to share their stories before they all got amnesia, and they are left with odd snippets of memory; the fact that a character has a clue about a particular ship, for instance, does not mean that they are from that ship, unless it is specifically stated in the clue.
- Names in *italics* are the names of players; names in **bold** are the names of characters in the game. The player's names have all been randomly changed from the names of the original party-goers.
- There are no ships represented which do not have an associated crew manifest.
- There are no crew members present who are not listed on a crew manifest.
- There are no paying passengers who are not listed on a passenger manifest.
- Each character's name reflects their nationality and sex. (e.g., **Felipe C. Ivarruz-Vicaza** is not a Scottish woman.) Note that English-speaking nationalities (e.g., English, American) may not have completely distinctive names. Character names were chosen semi-randomly from name databases of their respective nationalities.

  > **Edit**: Although some names are intentionally ambiguous, I have added to the crew and manifests annotations of the sex, if it is meant to be clear.
  >
  > > **Edit again**: This information has been moved to Hint 1.
- The sex of the players matches the sex of their characters. For the purpose of this puzzle, all players and characters are assumed to have one unambiguous sex, which is the conventional one for their name.

> **Edit**: - The scenario takes place in about 1800.

### Clues

#### Crew Manifests

> ***La Vierge du Bon Port***
>
> **Officers:**
>   Captain :  **Henrick R. Janssen**
>   1st Mate: **Seigfried D. Munser**
>   2nd Mate: **Margaret N. Salisbury**
>   Boatswain: **Hartmut R. Eckinger**
>
> **Sailors:**
>   Cook: **Dorothy W. Ramsey**
>   Seaman: **Carmel O'Brien**
>   Seaman: **Piperion Esquibel-Montero**
>   Seaman: **William P. Cotton**
>   Cabin Girl: **Peggy R. Cobb**

---

> ***The Sea Fox***
>
> **Officers:**
>   Captain: **Pulqueria Ceballos**
>   1st Mate: **Roger B. Sheppard**
>   2nd Mate: **Christopher H. Weber**
>   Boatswain: **Gennadi B. Sidorov**
>
> **Sailors:**
>    Cook: **Ronald McPherson**
>   Seaman: **Samuel E. Jennings**
>   Seaman: **Hu Wei-Xue**
>   Seaman: **James J. Graham**
>   Cabin Girl: **Charlotte C. Walpole**

---

> ***The Jonathan Cheswick***
>
> **Officers:**
>   Captain: **Henry R. Owen**
>   1st Mate: **Vasya S. Kalinnikov**
>   2nd Mate: **Tjeerd R. De Smet**
>   Boatswain: **Yan Fu-ju**
>
> **Sailors:**
>    Cook: **Fabian A. Schubach**
>   Seaman: **Virginia A. Allen**
>   Seaman: **Martha F. Woodard**
>   Seaman: **Timothy W. Hester**
>   Cabin Boy: **Nigel N. Salisbury**

---

> ***Gouden Leeuw***
>
> **Officers:**
>   Captain: **Elaine P. Wynn**
>   1st Mate: **Quentin P. Watson**
>   2nd Mate: **Arno Angélil**
>   Boatswain: **Margarita A. Jurivel**
>
> **Sailors:**
>    Cook: **Felipe C. Ivarruz-Vicaza**
>   Seaman: **Gareth R. Cavendish**
>   Seaman: **Wilma W. Chapman**
>   Seaman: **Lemar D. Malcombe**
>   Cabin Boy: **Samuel K. Pickett**

---

> ***Nuestra Señora de Cavadonga***
>
> **Officers:**
>   Captain: **Gertrude D. Hutchinson**
>   1st Mate: **Marietta N. Clarke**
>   2nd Mate: **Liao Jin-Zhong**
>   Boatswain: **Cecilia S. Ros-Gamiro**
>
> **Sailors:**
>    Cook: **Ruud D. Van Dijk**
>   Seaman: **Alexander H. Frost**
>   Seaman: **Findlay C. Scott**
>   Seaman: **Quentin R. Callaghan**
>   Cabin Boy: **Tremaine L. Higgins**

---

#### Passenger Manifests

> ***Passenger Manifest #1***
>
> **Jeanette J. Ambard**
>   **Chiaffredo Milanesi**
>   **Nazzareno D. Conti**
>   **Jean-Louis Fleuette**

---

> ***Passenger Manifest #2***
>
> **Austinafe Ajaranne**
>   **Jean-François Moreau**
>   **Louise-Violette Meserve**
>   **Uckbe Oronle**

---

> ***Passenger Manifest #3***
>
> **Eileen Mac Ateer**
>   **Ylesme Arrce**
>   **Maura I. Kiley**
>   **Eannare Imke**

---

#### Players

> **Player**: *Andrew*   **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Poor **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Andrew* stowed away on a ship bound for Bridgetown."
>   **Clue 2**: "*Andrew* lost a locket."

---

> **Player**: *Ann*  **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: Jamaican
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Ann*'s superior officer was American."

---

> **Player**: *Anthony*  **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Anthony* and *Margaret* got jobs on a ship in order to get home to America from France."
>   **Clue 2**: "The French ship was headed to Casa Blanca."

---

> **Player**: *Brian*    **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: English
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "None of the ships flew the same flags."

---

> **Player**: *Carrie*   **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: Spanish
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "One ship was a merchant ship sailing out of Rome."
>   **Clue 2**: "One of the merchant ships had a second mate who spoke two languages."
>   **Clue 3**: "The two English sailors aboard the Spanish ship always hassled the Scotsman."

---

> **Player**: *Charles*  **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: Strange
>   **Clothing**: Rich **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Rosemary* and *Charles* were on the same ship "
>   **Clue 2**: "*Charles* was overseeing a business venture."

---

> **Player**: *Christina*    **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: Spanish
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Christina* was the only Spaniard aboard her ship."
>   **Clue 2**: "The whaling ships had the same level of casualties among their crews, which was more than the other ships."
>   **Clue 3**: "**Alexander Frost** had an eyepatch."

---

> **Player**: *Debra*    **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: English
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "One of the ships flew an American flag and sailed out of Boston."
>   **Clue 2**: "The only male officer on the ship headed to Bridgetown was killed in the storm."
>   **Clue 3**: "*Debra* found a man by the name of **Albert** hiding in the hold of her ship."

---

> **Player**: *Dennis* **Sex**: M **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Officer **Eye patch?** : no  **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "The Cabin boy/girl was the only sailor to survive from the ship that sailed out of Kingston."
>
> > **Edit**: Cabin boy or girl

---

> **Player**: *Edward*   **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: Australian
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "Only one officer survived from 'The Jonathan Cheswick'"

---

> **Player**: *Elizabeth*    **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Elizabeth* and *Ryan* were on the same ship."
>   **Clue 2**: "*Elizabeth* was a cabin girl."
>   **Clue 3**: "One of the stowaways was named **Natalie Warner**."

---

> **Player**: *Emily*    **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: Chinese
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : yes    **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "Although 'Nuestra Señora de Cavadonga' was a Spanish ship, the captain was American."
>
> > **Edit**: Emily is female.

---

> **Player**: *Frank*    **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Poor **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "At least one officer from each ship perished in the storm."
>   **Clue 2**: "Three of the passengers on the ship sailing out of Veracruz were killed in the storm."

---

> **Player**: *Gary* **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: French
>   **Clothing**: Rich **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Sherry* and *Gary* were on the same ship."
>   **Clue 2**: "*Gary* was funding a mission of discovery and wanted to go along."

---

> **Player**: *George*   **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: Shakespearean English
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : yes    **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "The cook aboard *George's* ship perished in the storm."
>   **Clue 2**: "*George* was headed to Charleston."
>   **Clue 3**: "Only one Sailor from the "Gouden Leeuw" survived."

---

> **Player**: *Irene*    **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Poor **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Irene* met *Terry* when she stowed away on his ship. He found her, but agreed not to report her."
>   **Clue 2**: "Only one cook survived the storm."
>   **Clue 3**: "Two of the stowaways had professions for surnames: one that makes arrows, one that works with iron."

---

> **Player**: *Jack* **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: Scottish
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "Two of the captains went down with their ships."
>   **Clue 2**: "Two of the ships were whalers, and did not allow passengers."
>   **Clue 3**: "There are two freshly made graves on the island, which read 'R.I.P. **Virginia Allen**' and 'R.I.P. **Eileen Mac Ateer**'."

---

> **Player**: *Jason*    **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: Dutch
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Jason* was aboard a merchant ship."
>   **Clue 2**: "All the English ship's sailors survived the tempest."
>
> > **Edit**: Corrected "All the English sailors" to "All the English **ship's** sailors."

---

> **Player**: *Jennifer* **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Poor **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Jennifer* was a stowaway on a whaling ship."
>   **Clue 2**: "The ship which was sailing between two non-English-speaking ports has sailors from four different English-speaking countries."
>   **Clue 3**: "When the storm hit, the captain of the ship carrying the two Italian gentlemen assigned the cook to stick with **Signor Milanesi**, and another sailor to stay with **Signor Conti**; this decided the fates of the two gentleman."

---

> **Player**: *Joseph*   **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: English
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Joseph* was a cabin boy."
>   **Clue 2**: "The ship sailing out of Vera Cruz was not an exploration vessel."
>   **Clue 3**: "The last name of one of the stowaways was the same as the first name of the ship *Joseph* was on."

---

> **Player**: *Josephine*    **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Josephine* hired a Jamaican Cabin Boy with a peg leg for her ship."
>   **Clue 2**: "The captain of "Gouden Leeuw" had a hook hand."
>   **Clue 3**: "*Josephine* found a locket washed up on the beach with the initials "**PF**" engraved on it."

---

> **Player**: *Keith*    **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: Russian
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "One of the ships was an exploration ship that was headed to Buenos Aires to resupply on the way to Antarctica."
>   **Clue 2**: "Only one ship was sailing to a port that flew the same flag as the ship."
>
> > **Edit**: Changed "its home port" to "a port that flew the same flag as the ship", for clarity.

---

> **Player**: *Kevin*    **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "Each of the ships had set sail from a different port."
>
> > **Edit**: Kevin has an eye patch
> >     **Clue 2**: "One of the stowaways had the same last name as the first name of the captain of the westward-sailing whaler. (Don't ask how I remember this even while I have amnesia.)"

---

> **Player**: *Kimberly* **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : yes    **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "One ship was sailing from Bordeaux to Charleston."
>   **Clue 2**: "All of the second mates have eyepatches."
>   **Clue 3**: "One of the stowaways earned himself the nick-name 'Crazy **Parker**' because of his devil-may-care attitude about life."
>
> > **Edit**: Reworded Clue 3.

---

> **Player**: *Larry*    **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: German
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "The Captain of the Dutch ship did not wear an eyepatch."
>   **Clue 2**: "The Boatswain of "The Jonathan Cheswick" had full use of both hands."
>   **Clue 3**: "*Larry's* ship set sail from Bordeaux."

---

> **Player**: *Lori* **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "There was originally a stowaway on each ship, but one perished."

---

> **Player**: *Margaret* **Sex**: F   **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Anthony* and *Margaret* got jobs on a ship in order to get home to America from France."
>   **Clue 2**: "Whaling ships are not allowed to dock at Bridgetown."
>
> > Edit: Corrected "Bridgeport" to "Bridgetown".

---

> **Player**: *Megan*    **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: English
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Willie* and *Megan* met each other after being shipwrecked on the island."

---

> **Player**: *Patrick*  **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: Jamaican
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : yes
>   **Clue 1**: "*Patrick* was on a whaling ship."
>   **Clue 2**: "Two officers from the English ship survived the storm."
>   **Clue 3**: "No one who was aboard a merchant ship had a peg leg."

---

> **Player**: *Paul* **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: Italian
>   **Clothing**: Rich **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "Each of the ships was headed to a different destination."
>   **Clue 2**: "One of the ships suffered no casualties among the sailors."
>   **Clue 3**: "**Mme. Meserve** was known for her beautiful eyes."

---

> **Player**: *Raymond*  **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: Spanish
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "One ship was a Dutch merchant ship heading to its home port in Amsterdam."
>   **Clue 2**: "One of the boatswains was headed to Casa Blanca, where he was to be married and give up his life on the sea; tragically, he was killed in the storm."
>   **Clue 3**: "One of the stowaways carved their initials into the hull of the ship they were on: **JS**."

---

> **Player**: *Richard*  **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: French and German
>   **Clothing**: Officer  **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "The Spanish ship was sailing to Bridgetown."
>   **Clue 2**: "None of the sailors aboard "The Jonathan Cheswick" were maimed."
>   **Clue 3**: "The stowaway on *Richard's* ship was a handsome man with no visible disfigurement, but he was made to walk the plank."
>
> > **Edit**: For clarification, "maimed" in this context refers to eyepatch, hook-hand, and peg-leg, not to whether or not the sailors survived the storm.

---

> **Player**: *Rosemary* **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: Strange
>   **Clothing**: Rich **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Rosemary* and *Charles* were on the same ship"
>   **Clue 2**: "Each ship was named in the language of the country it was from."
>   **Clue 3**: "One of the stowaways was known as 'One-eyed **Pete**.'"

---

> **Player**: *Ryan* **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Elizabeth* and *Ryan* are on the same boat."
>   **Clue 2**: "Only one ship was sailing out of its home country."

---

> **Player**: *Sherry*   **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: French
>   **Clothing**: Rich **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : yes    **Peg Leg?** : yes
>   **Clue 1**: "*Sherry* discovered a stowaway named **Marie** searching through her baggage."
>   **Clue 2**: "*Sherry* and *Gary* were on the same ship."

---

> **Player**: *Terry*    **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: American
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : no **Hook Hand?** : no **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "The person who shares a first name with *Terry* is either Australian or English."
>   **Clue 2**: "*Irene* met *Terry* when she stowed away on his ship. He found her, but agreed not to report her."

---

> **Player**: *Victoria* **Sex**: F  **Language/Accent**: Irish
>   **Clothing**: Rich **Eye patch?** : yes    **Hook Hand?** : yes    **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Victoria* was on a boat with two Spaniards."
>   **Clue 2**: "The English ship had no passengers."
>   **Clue 3**: "Someone found a dog-eared and heavily-annotated copy of "Hamlet" washed up on the beach, with the initials '**G.R.C.**' printed on the inside cover."

---

> **Player**: *Willie*   **Sex**: M  **Language/Accent**: English
>   **Clothing**: Sailor   **Eye patch?** : yes **Hook Hand?** : no  **Peg Leg?** : no
>   **Clue 1**: "*Willie* and *Megan* met each other after being shipwrecked on the island."
>
> > **Edit**: *Willie* has an eye patch, not a hook hand.

---

### Hint 1

Some information in the puzzle may take some research, especially if one isn't familiar with names in different languages and historical geography.  Here is some information which is intended to be known, but which is not directly stated:

> The flags flown by the ten ports mentioned in 1800 were:
>
>  **Amsterdam**, Holland - **Dutch**
>  **Bordeaux**, France - **French**
>  **Boston**, Massachusetts - **American**
>  **Bridgetown**, Barbados - **British**
>  **Buenos Aires**, Viceroyalty of the Río de la Plata (today Argentina) - **Spanish**
>  **Casablanca**, Morocco - **Moroccan**
>  **Charleston**, North Carolina - **American**
>  **Kingston**, Jamaica - **British**
>  **Rome**, the **Roman Republic** Feb 1798 - Jun 1800, or the **Papal States** June 1800 - 1808. The difference is not significant here, since neither is otherwise represented in the puzzle. Although the Roman Republic was a French puppet state, it did have its own flag, and does not count as French in this puzzle.
>  * **Veracruz**, Viceroyalty of New Spain (now Mexico) - **Spanish**
>
>  The language and genders of the character names listed in the manifests are:
>
>  **La Vierge du Bon Port**
>  **Officers**
>  Captain: **Henrick R. Janssen**, Dutch, M
>  1stMate: **Seigfried D. Munser**, German, M
>  2ndMate: **Margaret N. Salisbury**, Anglophone, F
>  Boatswain: **Hartmut R. Eckinger**, German, M
>  **Sailors**
>  Cook: **Dorothy W. Ramsey**, Anglophone, F
>  Seaman: **Carmel O'Brien**, Irish, F
>  Seaman: **Piperion Esquibel-Montero**, Spanish, M
>  Seaman: **William P. Cotton**, Anglophone, M
>  Cabin Girl: **Peggy R. Cobb**, Anglophone, F
>
>  **The Sea Fox**
>  **Officers:**
>  Captain: **Pulqueria Ceballos**, Spanish, F
>  1st Mate: **Roger B. Sheppard**, Anglophone, M
>  2nd Mate: **Christopher H. Weber**, Anglophone, M
>  Boatswain: **Gennadi B. Sidorov**, Russian, M
>  **Sailors:**
>  Cook: **Ronald McPherson**, Anglophone, M
>  Seaman: **Samuel E. Jennings**, Anglophone, M
>  Seaman: **Hu Wei-Xue**, Chinese, ??
>  Seaman: **James J. Graham**, Anglophone, M
>  Cabin Girl: **Charlotte C. Walpole**, Anglophone, F
>
>  **The Jonathan Cheswick**
>  **Officers:**
>  Captain: **Henry R. Owen**, Anglophone, M
>  1st Mate: **Vasya S. Kalinnikov**, Russian, M
>  2nd Mate: **Tjeerd R. De Smet**, Dutch, M
>  Boatswain: **Yan Fu-ju**, Chinese, ??
>  **Sailors:**
>  Cook: **Fabian A. Schubach**, German, M
>  Seaman: **Virginia A. Allen**, Anglophone, F
>  Seaman: **Martha F. Woodard**, Anglophone, F
>  Seaman: **Timothy W. Hester**, Anglophone, M
>  Cabin Boy: **Nigel N. Salisbury**, Anglophone, M
>
>  **Gouden Leeuw**
>  **Officers:**
>  Captain: **Elaine P. Wynn**, Anglophone, F
>  1st Mate: **Quentin P. Watson**, Anglophone, M
>  2nd Mate: **Arno Angélil**, German first name, French last name, M
>  Boatswain: **Margarita A. Jurivel**, Spanish, F
>   **Sailors:**
>   Cook: **Felipe C. Ivarruz-Vicaza**, Spanish, M
>  Seaman: **Gareth R. Cavendish**, Anglophone, M
>  Seaman: **Wilma W. Chapman**, Anglophone, F
>  Seaman: **Lemar D. Malcombe**, Anglophone, M
>  Cabin Boy: **Samuel K. Pickett**, Anglophone, M
>
>  **Nuestra Señora de Cavadonga**
>  **Officers:**
>  Captain: **Gertrude D. Hutchinson**, Anglophone, F
>  1st Mate: **Marietta N. Clarke**, Anglophone, F
>  2nd Mate: **Liao Jin-Zhong**, Chinese, ??
>  Boatswain: **Cecilia S. Ros-Gamiro**, Spanish, F
>
>   **Sailors:**
>   Cook: **Ruud D. Van Dijk**, Dutch, M
>  Seaman: **Alexander H. Frost**, Anglophone, M
>  Seaman: **Findlay C. Scott**, Anglophone, M
>  Seaman: **Quentin R. Callaghan**, Anglophone, M
>  Cabin Boy: **Tremaine L. Higgins**, Anglophone, M
>
>  **Passenger Manifest #1**
>  **Jeanette J. Ambard**, French, F
>  **Chiaffredo Milanesi**, Italian, M
>  **Nazzareno D. Conti**, Italian, M
>  **Jean-Louis Fleuette**, French, M
>
>  **Passenger Manifest #2**
>  **Austinafe Ajaranne**, ??, ??
>  **Jean-François Moreau**, French, M
>  **Louise-Violette Meserve**, French, F
>  **Uckbe Oronle**, ?? ??
>
>  **Passenger Manifest #3**
>  **Eileen Mac Ateer**, Irish, F
>  **Ylesme Arrce**, ??, ??
>  **Maura I. Kiley**, Irish, F
>  **Eannare Imke**, ??, ??
>
>  Here, "Anglophone" means English, Scottish, American, Australian, or Jamaican.  1800 was before the Great Famine in Ireland, so a) the Irish diaspora to the colonies was less pronounced, making the presence of a clearly Irish name there less likely; in any case, and American or Australian (etc.) with an Irish name would also have had an Irish accent while speaking English; and b) a larger portion of Irish people spoke the Irish language, and so would not be "Anglophone" anyway.  This distinction only gives really new information for one name.

### Hint 2

> Although Scots were more likely to be mixed up into other parts of the British Empire (or America) by 1800 than the Irish, they do still have distinctive names; this is a one-way inference.  A person with a Scottish name is not necessarily Scottish, but a Scot will have a Scottish name. (For the purposes of the puzzle.)  The Scottish names are **Ronald McPherson** and **Findlay C. Scott**

Comment: ... wow! Impressive question.

Comment: The title of this puzzle is in no way misleading.

Comment: If gender is important, do you mind also listing the genders on the crew and passenger manifests, just so there's no confusion?

Comment: For several of the names, the fact that they are ambiguously gendered is a part of the puzzle. I will add the genders for the ones that are intended to be obvious.

Comment: I shouldn't say obvious.  I should say, "possible to determine with the possible help of an internet search."

Comment: @brendan In that case, you should have included names like "Ashley," "Lindsey," or "Kim," so people would make incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @KSmarts: I'm not trying to trip anyone up with the gender of names.  There's enough misdirection with the three pirates. It's just a fact that can be assumed to be known for some names, and not others.  If the name doesn't tell you the gender of the character, then it takes more information of another type to match them to a player.

Comment: I was reviewing the solution to make sure of the answer to kaine's question, and I found that I had made an error typing up the puzzle for SE.  There are actually four pirates!  I've changed the question.  Sorry, everyone.  At the party, I didn't tell the number of pirates.

Comment: ...Fine then... to make up for that: Are Pulqueria, Margarita, Felipe and Piperion the spanish names? Is Scotland considered a separate english speaking country?

Comment: @kaine - Yes, those are the Spanish names.  "Scottish" is considered distinct from "English" as the nationality of a character, as are "Jamaican" and "Irish," although these were not independent countries at the time that the scenario took place.

Comment: So could Jennifer mean English, Jamaican, Scottish, and Australian?

Comment: @kaine - That is a valid interpretation of the clue (I won't say if those are specifically the four countries).

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions but this is a hard question and I want to make sure I'm not missing anything stupid: Charlestown flew American; Amsterdam flew Dutch....did you mean Buenos Aires to fly Spanish flags or Bridgetown to fly English flags?

Comment: @Kaine - Yes, in 1800 Veracruz and Buenos Aires were still parts of the Spanish Empire, and Kingston and Bridgetown parts of the British Empire.

Comment: This is proving tricky. I thought I had a solution, but pulling it a little further showed a mistake in my working. Still, it’s proving to be a fun challenge. :-)

Comment: I think it would be easier to solve the Beale ciphers than working my way through this one.

Comment: I give up (for now). If anybody wants them, my notes are here: https://gist.github.com/alexwlchan/dc4bd8ce5fc5ce440cc6 I make no claims for accuracy, but it might help somebody else get started. I want to see a complete answer as much as anybody else, but time and motivation are rapidly diminishing.

Comment: @alexwlchan - A very good start.  Is everyone ready for a hint?

Comment: Two things: 1) I’ve posted a second attempt in the Gist, which reflects Richard’s actual clue, not my interpretation of it. 2) When Ann refers to her “superior officer”, does she mean the person directly above her in the pecking order?

Comment: @kaine True, but I restarted my solution using the nationality data, and it turns out I can do away with Debra in that part of the proof.

Comment: @kaine - The pirates always make statements that are logically false.  A statement with a null reference (e.g., "the ship with only one male officer," when there is no such ship) or an underdetermined reference (e.g., "The Spanish ship" when there are actually three Spanish ships) is not logically false or true. (Or, using the axiom "anything follows from a false hypothesis," is in fact always true.)

Comment: Turns out that I was mistaken, I need Debra’s statement. But oh well, it seems to work.

Comment: I keep making bad assumptions so I will ask again... Did you mean tense to be a clue such as with Terry's shared name being in present tense.

Comment: I assume the American and British ports are the only English-speaking ones?

Comment: I made some more edits to fix typos uncovered by alexwlchan's partial answer and my own attempt to write up the solution.  There's also another hint and some clarifications.  See comments under alexwlchan's answer for more details.

Comment: @kaine - No, the tense is not intended to be a clue.  I should change all the clues to be in past tense.

Answer (score 14):

> #### Answerer’s note
>
> *This is long. Like, really long. Pull up a chair*.
>
> *I’ve been working on this for several days, and I think it’s finally correct. I may have made a minor slip up somewhere – please let me know if I have! But I believe almost all of my deductions are correct, and the back of the puzzle is broken.*
>
> *There have been **three** major versions of this answer:*
>
> 1. *My initial attempt exposed a few mistakes in the original question, which was edited.*
> 2. *I revised some of my magic to use the new clues, and I was able to complete the puzzle. But @GentlePurpleRain pointed out a mistake: I said the only duplicated name was “Samuel” (in Terry’s clue), when “Quentin” is also duplicated.*
> 3. *I've moved some of the logic around Terry. The result is the same, but now I prove that he’s not Quentin.*
>
> *I won’t lie: if I was one of these castaways, I would have been killed by pirates long ago.*
>
> ***This answer is so long that spoiler blocks are impractical. Everything below this block will spoil you.***

### Nationality data

Start by filling in the grid with the accent/nationality of the party-goers and the manifests.

We immediately make the following deductions:

- *Richard* is the 2nd Mate of the *Leeuw*: **Arno Angélil**.
- The following people are all dead:

  - **Carmel O'Brien**, seaman on the *Vierge*
  - **Hu Wei-Xue**, seaman on the *Sea Fox*
  - **Fabian A. Schubach**, cook on the *Cheswick*
  - **Ruud D. Van Dijk**, cook on the *Cavadonga*

### Who are the pirates?

Now we want to find the pirates. If we know who they are, then we can trust the other clues.

Here's what we can deduce:

- ***Larry* is a pirate.**

  *Debra* refers to the "only male officer" on a ship. Every ship except the *Cavadonga* has at least two male officers, so she must be referring to **Liao Jin-Zhong**. There is one other Chinese officer on the manifest: **Yan Fu-ju** of the *Cheswick*.

  Only one Chinese officer survived: *Emily* (female). It follows that **Liao Jin-Zhong** is dead, and *Emily* is **Yan Fu-ju**. (This means one of *Debra*'s clues is true, so she is honest.)

  *Larry* tells us that the Boatswain of the *Cheswick* (**Yan Fu-ju**) has full use of both hands, but *Emily* has a hook hand, so he must be lying. Thus *Larry* is a pirate.

  > I am assuming that pirates do not make statements with null references; i.e., that I can trust that when *Debra* refers to the "only male officer" on a ship, said officer does actually exist.
- **At least one of *Edward*, *Frank* and *Patrick* is lying.**

  We can count 13 officers who survived, which means that 7 officers died. Now consider the following clues:

  - *Edward*: only 1 officer survived aboard the *Cheswick* (so 3 died).
  - *Frank*: at least 1 officer died on each ship.
  - *Patrick*: 2 officers on the English ship survived (so 2 died).

  If all three were correct, then at least 8 officers would be dead. Somebody is lying.
- ***Jason* is a pirate.**

  Consider the two (incompatible) accounts:

  - *Rosemary* tells us that each ship's name matches the language of its home country. Then the English ship would be either the *Sea Fox* or the *Cheswick*.
  - *Jason* tells us that all the sailors aboard the English ship survived, but (at this point) we know that every ship except the *Leeuw* has lost at least one sailor, so the English ship would be the *Leeuw*.

  Suppose *Jason* is honest. It must be that the *Leeuw* is the English ship, and all the sailors aboard survived. Then *Rosemary* is lying, and then so is *Charles* (as they both make the same statement).

  But *George* tells us that only one sailor from the *Leeuw* survived, so he must be lying. Now we have five pirates: *Larry*, *Rosemary*, *Charles*, *George*, and one of *Edward*/*Frank*/*Patrick*.
- **Either *George* or *Paul* is a pirate.**

  Consider the following two accounts:

  - *George* tells us that only one sailor survived on the *Gouden Leeuw*.
  - *Paul* tells us that there is a ship with no casualties among the sailors (this must be the *Leeuw*).

  Clearly they cannot both be correct.

We have narrowed down the pirates as follows:

1. *Jason*
2. *Larry*
3. One of *Edward*, *Frank* and *Patrick*
4. One of *George* and *Paul*

Since we know there are exactly four pirates, we have "found" them all. Everybody else can be trusted to be honest.

---

### Filling in the grid

With that in mind, we can fill in the grid.

First, let's just not some things that seem “obvious”, but now we have clarified:

- *Brian* tells us that each ship has a different flag.
- Per *Rosemary*, every ship is named in the language of its home country. Thus the *Vierge* is French, the *Leeuw* is Dutch and the *Cavadonga* is Spanish.

  The *Sea Fox* and *Cheswick* are British and American, but which is which is not yet known.
- *Kevin* tells us that each of the ships set sail from a different port. (These ports are Boston, Bordeaux, Kingston, Rome and Vera Cruz.)

Note, however, that we cannot be sure each ship is sailing to a different destination, as this is one of *Paul*'s clues, and he is a suspected pirate.

---

### Officers

Remember what we already know:

- ***Emily* is Boatswain on the *Cheswick*.**
- ***The 2nd Mate of the *Cavadonga* has perished.**

Let's start by sorting out some of the female officers:

- First, we note that the four female officers *Ann*, *Debra*, *Josephine* and *Kimberly* could occupy the following four roles:

  - 2nd Mate on the *Vierge*
  - Captain on the *Leeuw*
  - Captain or 1st Mate on the *Cavadonga*

  Since we have four survivors mapping to four roles, all four of these roles have survived.

  (In particular, if we can prove that there is only one party-goer who could be a given role, then that party-goer must be that role. In general, this is not the case, as that role could have perished.)
- ***Ann* was the 1st Mate on the *Cavadonga*.**

  She tells us that her superior officer is American. It then follows that:

  - She is not 2nd Mate on the *Vierge*, as she would have Dutch and German superiors.
  - She is not the captain of the *Leeuw* or the *Cavadonga*, as the captain does not have a superior officer.

  It follows that she is the 1st Mate of the *Cavadonga*.

  She also tells us that the captain of the *Cavadonga* is American, so we can rule out *Debra*. (We also learn this from *Emily*.)
- ***Kimberly* is the captain of the *Leeuw*.**

  *Josephine* tells us that the captain of the *Leeuw* has a hook hand, and so we can rule out *Josephine* and *Debra*. This leaves *Kimberly* as the only option.
- ***Debra* is 2nd Mate of the *Vierge*.**

  *Kimberly* tells us that all the 2nd Mates have eyepatches. Since *Josephine* does not, she is not a 2nd Mate. This leaves *Debra*.
- ***Josephine* is captain of the *Cavadonga*.**

  (Process of elimination)

We can use *Kimberly*'s clue to find another officer:

- ***Jason* is the captain of the *Vierge*.**

  He is Dutch, and there are two surviving Dutch officers: captain of the *Vierge*, and 2nd Mate on the *Cheswick*. Since 2nd Mates do not have eye patches, *Jason* is not a 2nd Mate.

  This means that the 2nd Mate of the *Cheswick* has perished.

And now we have enough information to pin down *Carrie* and *Christina*, the last two (surviving) female officers:

- There are three Spanish female officers: captain of the *Sea Fox*, Boatswain on the *Leeuw*, and Boatswain on the *Cavadonga*.

  According to *Jack*, two of the captains died. Since we already have three surviving captains (*Vierge*, *Leeuw* and *Cavadonga*), **the captains of the *Sea Fox* and *Cheswick* are dead.**
- ***Christina* is Boatswain on the *Cavadonga*.**

  She tells us that she is the only Spaniard on her ship. This means she is not on the *Leeuw*, as the cook of this ship is Spanish.

  Therefore:
- ***Carrie* is Boatswain on the *Leeuw*.**

We can't quite finish off the officers, because we need to know which of *Edward*, *Frank* and *Patrick* are lying. Let's move on, and we'll come back to them later.

---

### Sailors

Let's move on to fill in some of the sailor grid instead.

- *Elizabeth* is a cabin girl, so she must be aboard the *Vierge* or the *Sea Fox*. Thus *Ryan* is aboard one of these two ships also.
- *Anthony* is on the same ship as *Margaret*, who is a female sailor. There are no positions for female sailors on the *Cavadonga*, so *Anthony* cannot be on this ship.
- *Christina* tells us that **Alexander Frost** had an eyepatches, so if he survived, he is either *George* or *Willie*.
- *Joseph* was a cabin boy.
- According to *Richard*, none of the sailors on the *Jonathan Cheswick* were maimed, so we can rule out *George*, *Patrick* and *Willie* from working on this ship.
- The copy of *Hamlet* which *Victoria* finds has the initials **G.R.C.** inscribed in the cover. We may assume that if **Gareth** survived, he is *George*, as he is the only person with a “Shakespearean English” accent.
- As *Jack* found a grave for **Virginia Allen**, a seaman on the *Cheswick*, she must have perished.
- As *Josephine* is captain of the *Cavadonga* and hired a Jamaican with a peg leg for her cabin boy, if her cabin boy survived, he must be *Patrick*.

Once again, I seem to stuck. I can't see anything else we can deduce about the sailor grid, without going elsewhere. Let's move on and look at ships.

---

### Ships

- We already have the nationalities of the *Vierge*, *Leeuw* and *Cavadonga* from *Rosemary*.
- Per *Anthony*, the French ship (the *Vierge*) is destined for Casa Blanca.
- *Carrie* tells us that the ship sailing out of Rome was a merchant ship.

  She also tells us that there was a merchant ship with a bilingual 2nd Mate. The only bilingual officer on the manifest is the 2nd Mate of the *Leeuw*, so this must be a merchant ship. (We do not know if it is the same ship as in her first clue.)
- *Debra* tells us the American ship sailed out of Boston. *Ryan* tells us that only one ship was sailing out of its home country, so it follows that the French ship was not leaving Bordeaux.
- *Debra* also told that the only male officer on the ship to Bridgetown died, and we identified this ship as the *Cavadonga*.
- *Jack* tells us that the two whaling ships did not cary passengers. Combined with *Victoria*'s statement (there were no passengers on the English ship), and we conclude that the English ship was a whaler.
- Since whaling ships cannot stop at Bridgetown (from *Margaret*), the English ship was not heading there. And the Spanish ship was sailing to Bridgetown (*Richard*), so it's not a whaler.
- *Joseph* tells us the ship from Vera Cruz was not an exploration vessel.
- *Keith* tells us that an exploration ship was sailing to Buenos Aires.
- *Kimberly* tells us that there was a ship sailing from Bordeaux to Charleston. Since *Anthony* and *Margaret* were aboard this ship, and every ship left from a different port, this cannot be the *Cavadonga*.
- The *Leeuw* was a merchant ship heading to Amsterdam, according to *Raymond*.
- We know that *Jason* was captain of the *Vierge*, and he claimed to be aboard a merchant ship. Since he is a pirate, the *Vierge* is not a merchant ship.
- Assuming *Frank*'s clue does not contain a null reference, the ship sailing from Vera Cruz has passengers and so is not a whaler.

---

Now we can identify another pirate! This is what we know about the destination of each ship:

```
Vierge          Casa Blanca
Sea Fox         ???
Cheswick        ???
Leeuw           Amsterdam
Cavadonga       Bridgetown
```

We know from other clues that there is a ship heading for Buenos Aires (*Keith*) and Charleston (*Kimberly*). This means that all the ships are heading for different ports, which is one of *Paul*'s clues.

**So *Paul* is honest, and *George* is a pirate.**

This gives us more information:

- ***Raymond* is the cook aboard the *Leeuw*.**

  If *Paul* is honest, then there is one ship on which all the sailors survived. Earlier we showed that this must be the *Leeuw*, and *Raymond* is the only survivor left who could be the *Leeuw*'s cook.

  Note that the other possibility for *Raymond* (seamate 2 on the *Vierge*) has thus perished.
- **The cooks on the other ships are dead.**

  This is *Irene*'s clue: in particular, the cook on the *Vierge* and *Sea Fox* could both have been alive.
- **Jack is seaman 2 (Findlay) on the *Cavadonga*.**

  Since he is Scottish, he was either the cook on the *Sea Fox* (**Raymond**) or the seaman on the *Vierge* (**Findlay**). Since **Raymond** is dead, he must be **Findlay.**
- **George is seaman 1 (Gareth) on the *Leeuw*.**

  We know that **Gareth** survived (*Paul* tells us all the sailors from one ship survived; this is the *Leeuw*), and so from *Victoria*'s clue (the copy of *Hamlet* with **G.R.C.** inscribed; see above), he is the only possibility for **Gareth**.
- **Larry is the 1st Mate on the *Vierge*.**

  *Raymond* tells us that the Boatswain heading for Casa Blanca was killed. We now know that there is only one ship going to Casa Blanca, which is the *Vierge*.

  We already knew that *Larry* was either the 1st Mate or Boatswain on the *Vierge*, and since he survived, he must be the 1st Mate.

---

### Stowaways

Let's briefly consider the stowaways. We have enough information to find almost all of their first names and surnames.

- *Debra* found a stowaway named **Albert** (M).
- *Elizabeth* tells us of a stowaway named **Natalie Warner** (F).
- *Irene* gives us clues for two surnames: “one who makes arrows” (**Fletcher**) and “one that works with iron” (**Smith**).
- *Josephine* found a locket with the initials **PF**. This does not match anybody on the manifest, so it must belong to a stowaway.
- *Kevin* gives us a complicated clue about another surname.
- *Kimberly* tells us that one of the stowaways has the surname **Parker**.
- *Raymond* tells us of a stowaway whose initials were **JS**.
- *Rosemary* knows of a stowaway whose first name was **Pete**.
- *Sherry* found a stowaway named **Marie**.

Deductions we can make:

- We have five first names/initials (**Albert**, **Natalie**, **Pete**, **Marie** and **J**). Thus the **P** in **PF** is **Pete**.
- We have four surnames (**Warner**, **Fletcher**, **Smith**, **Parker**) and a clue from *Kevin*. His clue tells us that the final last initial is one of **H**, **P** or **E** (based on the first names of all the captains of non-whaling ships). Thus the **F** in **PF** is **Fletcher**.

Now we can give some stowaways their real names:

- ***Andrew* is Pete Fletcher.**

  He lost a locket, and *Josephine* found a locket with the initials **PF**. It must be his locket.
- ***Jennifer* is Natalie Warner.**

  Since **Marie** was found by *Sherry*, **Marie** must have been aboard a passenger-carrying ship. But *Jennifer* was on a whaling ship, and whalers do not carry passengers, so she must be the other stowaway.
- ***Irene* is Marie, and *Frank* is Albert.**

  (Process of elimination.)

And some other stowaway-based deductions:

- Since *Andrew* was headed for Bridgetown, he is aboard the *Cavadonga*.
- The male stowaway on *Richard*'s ship (the *Leeuw*) had no disfigurements, but both the surviving male stowaways have eye patches. It follows that there is no surviving stowaway from the *Leeuw* (per *Lori*, each stowaway is aboard a different ship).
- *Terry* tells us that he shares a name with one of the other crew members.
  Thus his name is either **Samuel** or **Quentin**.

  He was on the same ship as *Irene*, so he is not sailing on the *Leeuw* or the *Cavadonga*. But the only sailor named Quentin is not on the *Cavadonga*, so he must be named Samuel, and the other is Samuel is either English or Australian.

  (I'm assuming that as *Patrick* is Jamaican, neither of them are *Terry*'s namesake.)

  There is a Samuel on the *Sea Fox* and the *Leeuw*. We know that *Irene* is not aboard the *Leeuw*, so nor is Terry. Thus *Terry* is Seaman 1 on the *Sea Fox*, and *Irene* has stowed away on this ship.
- *Debra* found **Albert** (*Frank*) aboard the *Vierge*. It follows that *Jennifer* was aboard the *Cheswick*, and so the *Cheswick* is a whaler.

---

At this point, my strategy breaks down a little. I've filled in quite a lot of the grids, and the rest of my deductions are scattered all over the map.

- *Anthony* and *Margaret* were both going home to America (the port at Charleston). This means they were on the *Sea Fox* or the *Cheswick*, as the other ships are known not to be travelling to Charleston.
- ***Victoria* is Maura I. Kiley, and she is sailing on the *Leeuw*.**

  *Jack* tells us that he found a grave for **Eileen Mac Ateer**. *Victoria* is Irish, and there were only two Irish passengers on the manifest. Since the first is dead, she must be the latter.

  She tells us that she was on a boat with two Spaniards, which must be the *Leeuw*. It follows that the *Leeuw* is the ship of Passenger Manifest #3.
- According to *Dennis*, only the cabin boy/girl survived on the ship that sailed out of Kingston.

  The *Sea Fox*, *Leeuw* and *Cavadonga* all have known survivors who are not cabin crew, so they are not sailing from Kingston. Note also that the surviving women sailors force a non-cabin survivor on the *Cheswick*: Seaman 2.

  It follows that the *Vierge* is sailing out of Kingston. Then all the other crew on the *Vierge* is dead.
- Since *Ryan* is travelling with *Elizabeth*, who is a cabin girl, neither of them are aboard the *Vierge*. The only other cabin girl is on the *Cheswick*, so they must be on this ship.

  We deduce that *Elizabeth* is the cabin girl and *Ryan* is seaman 3.
- We can deduce the nationality of the final two ships. Consider:

  - We know the *Cheswick* is a whaler.
  - We know that the *Cheswick* and *Sea Fox* are heading for Buenos Aires (ES) and Charleston (US), but we don't know which.
  - We know that the English ship is a whaler.
  - We know that the American ship must be heading to Buenos Aires as an explorer, because only one ship is heading for its home port, and this is the *Leeuw*.

  It follows that the *Cheswick* is the English ship, and the *Sea Fox* is the American ship.
- **We can trust *Frank*.**

  Since the *Cheswick* is the English ship, either *Edward* or *Patrick* is lying:

  - *Edward*: only 1 officer survived aboard the Cheswick (so 3 died).
  - *Patrick*: 2 officers on the English ship survived (so 2 died).

  And so *Frank* is in the clear. He tells us that at least one officer died aboard each ship.
- ***Dennis* is the 1st Mate of the *Sea Fox*, and *Kevin* is the 2nd Mate.**

  *Dennis* and *Kevin* fill two of three roles: 1st and 2nd Mate on the *Sea Fox*, and 1st Mate on the *Leeuw*.

  Every officer aboard the *Leeuw*, except the 1st Mate, is known to have survived. So from *Frank*'s clue, the 1st Mate on the *Leeuw* has died.

  Since *Dennis* does not have an eye patch, he cannot be a 2nd Mate (*Kimberly*), and the result follows.
- *Carrie* tells us that the two English sailors on the *Cavadonga* hassled the Scotsman. We know who the Scotsman on the *Cavadonga* is (*Jack*, Seaman), but not the other sailors.

  We also know that the cabin boy is Jamaican (*Josephine*) and the cook is Dutch (nationality/name). This means the other two seamen are English, and so we may rule out *Edward* and *Patrick* as seamen on this ship.

  By a process of elimination, *Willie* is seaman 1, and *Brian* is seaman 3.
- *Jennifer* talks about a ship sailing between two non-English-speaking ports. Let's work out which this is:

  - Not the *Vierge*, as it sails from Kingston
  - Not the *Sea Fox*, as it sails from Boston
  - Not the *Cheswick*, as it's going to Charleston
  - Not the *Cavadonga*, as it's going to Bridgetown.

  So she must be referring to the *Leeuw*. So far we know two sailors on this ship:

  - *Raymond*, cook, Spanish
  - *George*, seaman, (Shakespearean) English

  She tells us that the ship has sailors from four different English-speaking countries. We may deduce that *Joseph* and *Megan* are not aboard the *Leeuw* (as there is already an English sailor.)

  (This tells us that *Joseph* is cabin boy aboard the *Cheswick*.)

  Then by a process of elimination, *Edward* is the cabin boy (Australian) and *Patrick* is seaman 3 (Jamaican). Since *Anthony* is not aboard this ship, *Margaret* is not seaman 2, so this must be *Lori* (America).

  By a process of elimination, we deduce the final three sailors:

  - *Anthony* and *Margaret* are both seamen on the *Cheswick*
  - *Megan* is the cabin girl on the *Vierge*
- We know the *Cavadonga* is not a whaler, and we know the non-whaling purposes of the *Sea Fox* and *Leeuw*. Since there are two whalers, the *Vierge* must be a whaler also.

We can now identify the final pirate:

- We know from *Christina* that the two whaling ships (the *Vierge* and the *Cheswick*) have the same casualty rates.

  Five sailors and officers have died on the *Vierge*. Only four are confirmed to have died on the *Cheswick*, and possibly one more (depending on whether *Keith* is on the *Sea Fox* or *Cheswick*).

  We deduce that *Keith* is the Boatswain on the *Sea Fox*, and the 1st Mate of the *Cheswick* died.

  **So *Edward* is honest, and *Patrick* is lying.**

  (We could have spotted this sooner – Patrick is on the *Leeuw*, which is not a whaling ship, but he claims that he is.)

In summary, the four pirates are ***George*, *Jason*, *Larry* and *Patrick***.

A few more notes before I summarise the results:

- *Sherry* found *Irene*/**Marie** in her luggage. Since *Irene* was aboard the *Sea Fox*, so are *Gary* and *Sherry*.
- When *Jennifer* refers to a ship carrying **Signor Milanesi** and **Signor Conti**, this must be either the *Sea Fox* or the *Cavadonga* (passenger carrying ship; not the *Leeuw* because it's attached to a different manifest).

  The cook on both of these ships died, so **Signor Milanesi** must also be dead. It follows that *Paul* (the only surviving Italian passenger) is **Conti**.
- *Charles* was overseeing a business venture, so he and *Rosemary* were not aboard the *Sea Fox* (which was an explorer).
- *Kevin*'s clue about a stowaway's surname refers to the “westward-sailing whaler”. The *Vierge* is sailing Kingston to Casa Blanca (eastward), while the *Cheswick* is sailing Bordeaux to Charleston (westward).

  The captain of the *Cheswick* is **Henry R. Owen**, so one of the stowaways has the last name **Henry**.

  So we know that the surnames of **Marie** and **Albert** are **Henry** and **Parker** (as the dead stowaway was **JS**).

  *Kimberly* tells us that **Parker** had a “devil-may-care attitude about life”. Since **Albert**/*Frank* has an eyepatch, but **Marie**/*Irene* is unmaimed, I'm going to assume this means that *Frank* is **Parker**.
- Since *Charles* and *Rosemary* both survived from the same ship, they must be on the merchant ship leaving Rome. (The ship from Vera Cruz lost three passengers.)
- The *Cavadonga* and *Leeuw* are sailing out of Rome and Vera Cruz. Since *Ryan* tells us only one ship is sailing out of its home country, and the American ship is already sailing out of Boston, we deduce the *Cavadonga* is sailing out of Rome. And thus it is a merchant ship.
- The ship sailing out of Vera Cruz (the *Leeuw*) lost three passengers (*Frank*), so *Victoria*/**Maura** are the only survivors from passenger manifest #1.
- Since *Charles* and *Gary* are travelling for different purposes, they must be on different ships. We deduce that:

  - *Gary* is **Jean-Louis Fleuette** on manifest #1, and since he's funding a discovery mission, this must be the *Sea Fox*
  - *Sherry* is **Jeanette J. Ambard**
  - *Charles* and *Rosemary* are **Austinafe Ajaranne** and **Uckbe Oronle** (but I don't know which is which) on manifest #2, and aboard the *Cavadonga*.

---

### Summary

An `X` next to a name means this person was a pirate.

Officers:

```
  Party-goer    Ship          Position        Real name
========================================================================
  Ann           Cavadonga     1st Mate
  Carrie        Leeuw         Boatswain
  Christina     Cavadonga     Boatswain
  Debra         Vierge        2nd Mate
  Dennis        Sea Fox       1st Mate
  Emily         Cheswick      Boatswain
X Jason         Vierge        Captain
  Josephine     Cavadonga     Captain
  Keith         Sea Fox       Boatswain
  Kevin         Sea Fox       2nd Mate
  Kimberly      Leeuw         Captain
X Larry         Vierge        1st Mate
  Richard       Leeuw         2nd Mate
```

Passengers:

```
  Party-goer    Ship          Position        Real name
========================================================================
  Anthony       Cheswick      Seaman 3
  Brian         Cavadonga     Seaman 3
  Edward        Leeuw         Cabin boy
  Elizabeth     Sea Fox       Cabin girl
X George        Leeuw         Seaman 1
  Jack          Cavadonga     Seaman 2
  Joseph        Cheswick      Cabin boy
  Lori          Leeuw         Seaman 2
  Margaret      Cheswick      Seaman 2
  Megan         Vierge        Cabin girl
X Patrick       Leeuw         Seaman 3
  Raymond       Leeuw         Cook
  Ryan          Sea Fox       Seaman 3
  Terry         Sea Fox       Seaman 1
  Willie        Cavadonga     Seaman 1
```

Passengers:

```
  Party-goer    Real name               Ship
========================================================================
  Charles       (Either Austinafe Ajaranne or Uckbe Oronle)
                                        Cavadonga
  Gary          Jean-Louis Fleuette     Sea Fox
  Paul          Nazzareno D. Conti      Sea Fox
  Rosemary      (Either Austinafe Ajaranne or Uckbe Oronle)
                                        Cavadonga
  Sherry        Jeanette J. Ambard      Sea Fox
  Victoria      Maura I. Kiley          Leeuw
```

Stowaways:

```
  Party-goer    Real name               Ship
========================================================================
  Andrew        Pete Fletcher           Cavadonga
  Frank         Albert Parker           Vierge
  Irene         Marie Henry             Sea Fox
  Jennifer      Natalie Warner          Cheswick
```

Ships:

```
  Ship        Type        Home country    Last port       Destination
========================================================================
  Vierge      Whaler      France          Kingston        Casa Blanca
  Sea Fox     Explorer    America         Boston          Buenos Aires
  Cheswick    Whaler      England         Bordeaux        Charleston
  Leeuw       Merchant    Netherlands     Vera Cruz       Amsterdam
  Cavadonga   Merchant    Spain           Rome            Bridgetown
```

Comment: I was checking through your solution, and found a typo in the puzzle!  I'm sorry, I know redoing things takes a huge amount of time for everyone who is still working on it.  You were correct, that there was no way to distinguish Kevin and Dennis.  However, Kevin is supposed to have an eye patch.  This is a little ironic, because Kevin was my part at the party.

There is also a problem with the "Alexander Frost had an eye patch" clue.  I'll need to rework part of the puzzle myself to correct it; it's not obvious from inspection what the correct clue is (or if something else is off).

Comment: There is also a missing clue, which provides the missing last name for the stowaways.

Comment: @brendan I see the fix to the Dennis/Kevin clue, the and the Willie clue. Nothing on “Alexander Frost” yet. Is it worth redoing my solution as best I can, ignoring that clue, or should I hold off until you’re done?

Comment: The changes I made have fixed the problem with Alexander Frost.

Comment: @brendan I’ve revised my answer to reflect the new clues. I think this is all correct, but I can’t tell Charles and Rosemary apart. Have I missed something?

Comment: Your summary doesn't list the real names of any of the crew.

Comment: You mention that Terry must be one of the Samuels, because it's the only name that's duplicated, but there are also two Quentins.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain 1) I was too lazy to put the real names on; I was going to add them when I was sure this was correct. (My hands hurt, ow.) 2) Good catch on the Quentin. I’ll have a look and see if I can patch up the solution.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I’ve moved around the Terry logic. He’s still called Samuel, not Quentin, but now we only prove that in the section on stowaways.

Comment: @alexwlchan - Heroic! But... You conclude that *Willie* is **Alexander H. Frost** and *Brian* is **Quentin R. Callaghan** (seamen on *Cavadonga*), by process of elimination. How do you know that both **Alexander** and **Quentin C.** survived?

Comment: @alexwlchan - I know some of the clues stretch logic a little bit (for instance, the lost locket must be the same as the found one, the person who speaks Shakespearean English must be the one with a copy of Hamlet) but the intention was not that a devil-may-care attitude indicates an eye-patch.

Comment: @brendan I don’t know; I’ll have a look at my “process of elimination” line in the morning. As the “devil-may-care” line, if that doesn’t work, I argue thusly: 1) We know that if **JS** is male; they didn’t survive. (*Andrew* has the **PF** locket; *Debra* finds **Albert**). 2) *Kimberly* uses pronoun “himself” to describe **Parker**, ergo **Albert Parker**. Or is the problem further back? [The result is the same, I just don’t use the “devil-may-care” attitude bit]

Comment: @alexwlchan - Excellent, that is the intended use of the "Crazy Parker" clue. At the original party, "*Frank*" actually acted crazy as part of his costume/persona, so it was obvious which stowaway was "Crazy Parker."  Or, it would have been, if the pirates hadn't killed everyone off before anyone even assembled a complete set of clues.  I realized late that that element hadn't made it into the written version, so I improvised something else.  The thing about the westward-sailing whaler, by the way, was an original clue, it was just accidentally omitted.

Comment: You conclude that Kimberly is captain of the Leeuw because second mates all have eyepatches.  You conclude that Jason is Captain of the Vierge because Second Mates do not have eyepatches.  I believe there may be an error somewhere in that logic.